# Getting errors while trying to send POST with Rails & React & jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs, post

I am new to React and I'm making Twitter-ish app for my practice.
I've succeeded to get the list of my tweets, however, I'm stuck in posting a new tweet (ajax POST).

I get these 2 errors on my Chrome console tab when hitting "submit":
1. POST http://localhost:3000/tweets/create 400 (Bad Request)
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined

And I have this error on my terminal log:
1. ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: tweet):

I've been googling all day yet I haven't found a solution. Can anyone please help me. Any little advise would be appreciated.

My codes are as follows:

TweetsPage.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import NewTweet from  './NewTweet'
import Tweets from './Tweets'

class TweetsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tweets: [],
      tweet: '',
    };
    this.onSubmit2 = this.onSubmit2.bind(this);
  }
  loadTweetsFromServer() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/tweets/index.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      cache: false,
      success: (data) => {
        this.setState({
          tweets: data
        });
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error(url, status, err.toString());
      },
    });
  }
  onSubmit2(value) {
    console.log(value)
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/tweets/create',
      dataType: 'json', // I'm not even sure if json is the right choice.
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      data: {
        tweet: this.state.tweet
      },
      success: (data) => {
        this.loadTweetsFromServer();
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error(url, status, err.toString());
      },
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadTweetsFromServer();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NewTweet onSubmit1={this.onSubmit2} />
        <Tweets tweets={this.state.tweets} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TweetsPage;
```

NewTweet.js:

```
import React from 'react'

class NewTweet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tweet: ''
    };
    this.getInput = this.getInput.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  getInput(e) {
    this.setState({
      tweet: e.target.value
    });
  }
  onSubmit() {
    this.props.onSubmit1(this.state.tweet);
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <textarea onChange={this.getInput}></textarea>
      <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>submit</button>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NewTweet;
```

tweets_controller.rb:

```
def create
    tweet = Tweet.new(create_params)
    tweet.user_id = current_user.id
    tweet.save
end

private
  def create_params
    params.require(:tweet).permit(:user_id, :tweet)
  end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
get 'tweets/index' => 'tweets#index'
post 'tweets/create' => 'tweets#create'
```

I'm calling TweetsPage on index.html.erb using `react_component`. (Note: I'm also importing Tweets in TweetsPage, but I'm going to skip it because that part is working fine.)
That `console.log` in `onSubmit2` within TweetPage.js is giving me what I type in (as it should), so I suppose it's the ajax POST part that's giving me a headache. Please let me know if I'm missing any information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onSubmit2` you're passing `this.state.tweet` into the data in the ajax call, but that's always empty string. The value is in the `value` variable. Try using that instead.

`this.state` is per component, so even though you called `this.setState` in `NewTweet` it doesn't affect the state inside `TweetsPage`.

Also in the error handler in `onSubmit2` you are using an undefined variable `url`.

Comment: So I fixed my code in `onSubmit2` and it solved the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So I changed `onSubmit2` like below and it solved the problem.

```
onSubmit2(value) {
    console.log(value)
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/tweets/create';
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'text',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      data: {
        tweet: value
      },
      success: (data) => {
        this.loadTweetsFromServer();
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error(url, status, err.toString());
      },
    });
  }
```